# Pascal - How to write a quotation mark ' as a string?

Tags: string, pascal

In pascal we assign a value to a string with a double single-quote. What if we want to write out a single quotation mark as a string?

how to write out '?
So I want to echo out a string like "It's a good day", but it cant cause there is a single quotation mark that will destroy the entire string.

thanks!

Comment: My Pascal is way rusty, but can you try preceding \ before ' : "It\'s a good day"

Comment: @m_pOatrix nope, doesnt work

Comment: according to http://www.irietools.com/iriepascal/progref10.html, try having two ' making ''.... "It''s a good day"

Comment: http://hyperpolyglot.org/pascal#strings

Comment: @m_pOatrix the double single quote works, but not the backlash. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if Freepascal follows Pascal dialect, then you type the single quote twice.

`It''s a good day`

There are other escape sequences described at http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse8.html